# select in HQL (hibernate)

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have a table in mysql which has just on record.
when I execute following hql query in netbeans HQL I got the following answer which is correct:

query:

```
from Customer as cust
```

response:

```
CustomerID   PhoneNumber   MainAddress   SubAddress      RequesstNumber   Name

1            22334455       Niavaran      shahrake naft     3            Javad
```

but when I execute this query by select it do not work correctly.

query:

```
select cust.name from Customer as cust
```

response:

```
Bytes         Bytes    Bytes    Bytes    Chars    Chars

[B@16bdee0
```

does anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate queries are case-sensitive. Perhaps you should try `cust.Name` instead of `cust.name`.

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
from Customer as cust
```

it litterally means that you select all columns:

```
select * from Customer as cust
```

Concerning your second request, it is strange. Could you post your exact mapping ?

Comment: I understand. You showed your request (HQL) but you didn't provide your mapping (.hbm file for example, or annotated entities). That's what I was asking for.